# add text after dataGrid cell

Tags: asp.net, gridview, templatefield

This is dataGrid . How to add text(string) after `<%# Bind("Value") %>` 
for example 123.432 and i want after any record to have "$" dolar sign

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Стойност">
     <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Value") %>'>
        </asp:TextBox>
     </EditItemTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="LabelValue" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Value") %>'>
        </asp:Label>
     </ItemTemplate>
     <ControlStyle Width="100px" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<% String.Format("{0}$",Eval("Value")); %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take benefit of [Standard Numeric Format String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

```
<asp:Label ID="LabelValue" runat="server" 
            text='<%# Bind("Value").ToString("C", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) %>'/>
```

which is a standard format available with C#. 

But you want to show it in the last then you can simply add it in the last.

Comment: I write this : <asp:Label ID="LabelValue" runat="server"  Text='<%# Bind("Value").ToString("C", en-US) %>'></asp:Label>   but this giving me Parse error :A call to Bind was not well formatted.  Please refer to documentation for the correct parameters to Bind.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="LabelValue" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Value") %>'>
        </asp:Label>
         $
 </ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [MaskedEdit extender](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx) in [ajax toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act.ashx) if you already using [ajax toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act.ashx) in your project.  `MaskedEdit extender` can be use in edit template and it will handle the mask on client side you don't want to worry about value and $ sign when you read the value back.

without using ajax toolkit you can use one label for $ sign and textbox for value field on edit template. In normal template also use two labels for both value and $ sign. then it will be easy to read the values.